# Is there a way to run an executable on DreamHost through PHP?

Tags: php, executable, dreamhost

I've been scratching my head trying to run an executable file server-side, but nothing is working. My PHP Code is below, and it works in XAMPP; however, when I migrated it to DreamHost, it stopped working. My vague understanding is that "exec," "shell_exec," etc. are disabled, but nothing I try reenables it. Are there any workarounds?

The PHP Code:

```
<?PHP
$retval = shell_exec('My_Executable.exe');
echo $retval;
?>
```

Comment: More than likely your hosting on DreamHost is on shared hosting where they prevent the use of exec, shell_exec, etc. Your best bet is to set up your own VPS/web server where you can control what's run/executed. Companies like DigitalOcean, Vultr, etc will be your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

Often times on shared hosting, they will lock down the php.ini to not allow shell_exec.

Here is a forum post at DreamHost talking about this exact topic:

https://discussion.dreamhost.com/t/warning-shell-exec/37133/3

Here is another one:

https://discussion.dreamhost.com/t/php-exec-help/38860/7

As pointed out by [Darren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2518525/darren) above, you might want to try to install your own version of PHP or use a dedicated hosting solution like Vultr or DO vs a shared one.